# Google map disappears from Bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to display a Google map inside a Bootstrap modal in my React app.

My modal will show the map only when `this.props.showMap` is set, like so:

```
export default class MapModal extends Component {
  ...

  componentDidMount() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {...});
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', () => {
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    });
  }
  render() {
      return (
        <div className = 'modal fade' id = 'myModal' role = 'dialog'>
          <div className = 'modal-dialog'>
            <div className = 'modal-content'>
            ...
            {
              this.props.showMap ?
                <div id = 'map' />
                :
                null
            }
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The button which opens up the modal is like so:

```
<MapModal showMap={this.state.showMap} />
...

<button
  type="button"
  onClick={() => { this.setState({ showMap: true }); } }
  data-toggle="modal"
  data-target="#myModal"
  >
  Show
</button>
```

The modal displays the map correctly, unless I switch the value of `this.state.showMap` from `true` to `false`.

For instance, when I open the modal with `this.state.showMap` as `false`, the map gets removed from the modal (as expected). But when I try to open the modal again, with `this.state.showMap` as `true`, the map still doesn't appear.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: How are you changing the showMap state when re-opening, and have you checked that the value is actually changing?

Comment: @Jayce444 Actually, it's not the state, it's the props which is checked in the condition. And `this.props.showMap` is set while opening the modal. I've updated the question now :)

Comment: I think you have to execute the init code for the map after you created the dom element with the id map.

Comment: @SimonMüller I thought this too, but I didn't wanted to reinitialize the maps every time I open up the modal, because that may lead to slower performance and/or mem leaks. What happens to the previous map's instance if I try to initialize a new instance when the map is not showing up? Is the previous instance disposed off correctly, or will that lead to multiple copies of maps on the same page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Because when you change the showMap to false, you have already removed the map from the Dom object. So you have to init the map again.
2. Alternatively you can add a css class or inline style to display or hide the map instead of render null.